# Stream youtube video WordPress widget

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, youtube

Hi I am trying to make a custom wordpress widget that allows the user to enter the title and url of the video which is then shown in a bootstrap modal on the front end.

The problem I'm having is that to close the video when the modal window closes I have used this bit of javascript to remove the source attribute and replace it when the modal is opened (well thats my plan anyway).  It works if you paste the url of the video into the src ="youtube video"

but I want to use a variable so the user can change the url but it just outputs the scipt () instead of the url.  My plugin.php looks like this.  Thnks for any help I am still learning so it is quite basic but I might be missing something silly.

```
 <?php
/*
Plugin Name: Site Plugin for Zeezevents.co.uk
Description: Site specific code changes for Zeezevents.co.uk
*/
/* Start Adding Functions Below this Line */
// Creating the widget
class wpb_widget extends WP_Widget {

function __construct() {
parent::__construct(
// Base ID of your widget
'wpb_widget', 

// Widget name will appear in UI
__('Zeezevents Videos', 'wpb_widget_domain'),

// Widget description
array( 'description' => __( 'play Youtube videos widget', 'wpb_widget_domain' ), )
);
}

// Creating widget front-end
// This is where the action happens
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
$videourl =  apply_filters( 'video_url', $instance['videourl'] );
$title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
// before and after widget arguments are defined by themes
echo $args['before_widget'];
if ( ! empty( $title ) )
echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
echo $videourl;
// This is where you run the code and display the output  
json_encode($videourl);
echo __( '<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<a class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="link">
  Watch Video
</a>

<script type = "text/javascript">


  jQuery("#link").click(function () {

        var src = " <?php echo ( $videourl ); ?> "

        jQuery("#myModal iframe").attr("src", src);
    });
</script>', 'wpb_widget_domain' );
echo $args['after_widget'];
}

// Widget Backend
public function form( $instance ) {
if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
$title = $instance[ 'title' ];

}
else {
$title = __( 'Videos', 'wpb_widget_domain' );

}
if ( isset( $instance[ 'videourl' ] ) ){
        $videourl = $instance[ 'videourl' ];
       }
       else {  $videourl = __( 'Videos', 'wpb_widget_domain' );}
// Widget admin form
?>
<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label> 
<input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'videourl' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'URL:' ); ?></label>
<input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'videourl' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'videourl' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $videourl ); ?>" />
</p>
<?php 
}

// Updating widget replacing old instances with new
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
$instance = array();
$instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';

$instance['videourl'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['videourl'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['videourl'] ) : '';
return $instance;
}
} // Class wpb_widget ends here

// Register and load the widget
function wpb_load_widget() {
    register_widget( 'wpb_widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpb_load_widget' );

/* Stop Adding Functions Below this Line */
?>
```

and the modal is like this

```
       <!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Egypt 2 Africa 2013</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <iframe width="560" height="315" src="<?php echo ($videourl); />" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', 
    function () {
    jQuery('#myModal iframe').removeAttr('src');  

})

</script >
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out!! =)  I took the jquery out of the echo and it works now.  As you can prob tell I am a novice but determined to learn how to program.  My next step is to extract the video id from the end of the url the user has entered in order to embed the video.  Can any one direct me to a good tutorial which explains the process?  Thanks for any comments.

Edit: as suggested my edited code

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Site Plugin for Zeezevents.co.uk
Description: Site specific code changes for Zeezevents.co.uk
*/
/* Start Adding Functions Below this Line */
// Creating the widget
class wpb_widget extends WP_Widget {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct(
        // Base ID of your widget
        'wpb_widget', 

        // Widget name will appear in UI
        __('Zeezevents Videos', 'wpb_widget_domain'),

        // Widget description
        array( 'description' => __( 'play Youtube videos widget', 'wpb_widget_domain' ), )
        );
}

// Creating widget front-end
// This is where the action happens
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {

$videourl =  apply_filters( 'video_url', $instance['videourl'] );
$title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );
// before and after widget arguments are defined by themes
echo $args['before_widget'];
if ( ! empty( $title ) )
echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];



// This is where you run the code and display the output  

echo __( '<div class="container-fluid"><!-- Button trigger modal -->
<a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" id="link">
<img src="http://zeezevents.co.uk/Images/egypt2africa.jpg" class="img-thumbnail"/>
</a>

</div>', 'videourl' );
  ?>


<script type = "text/javascript">


  jQuery("#link").click(function () {

        var src = "<?php echo $videourl; ?>";

        jQuery("#myModal iframe").attr("src", src);
    });
</script>

 <?php
echo $args['after_widget'] ;

}

// Widget Backend
public function form( $instance ) {
    if ( isset( $instance[ 'title' ] ) ) {
    $title = $instance[ 'title' ];

    }
    else {
    $title = __( 'Videos', 'wpb_widget_domain' );

    }
    if ( isset( $instance[ 'videourl' ] ) ){
            $videourl = $instance[ 'videourl' ];
           }
           else {  $videourl = __( 'Videos', 'wpb_widget_domain' );
           }
    // Widget admin form
    ?>
    <p>
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>" />
    <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'videourl' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'URL:' ); ?></label>
    <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'videourl' ); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'videourl' ); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $videourl ); ?>" />
    </p>
    <?php
}

// Updating widget replacing old instances with new
public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
$instance = array();
$instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';

$instance['videourl'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['videourl'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['videourl'] ) : '';
return $instance;
}
} // Class wpb_widget ends here

// Register and load the widget
function wpb_load_widget() {
    register_widget( 'wpb_widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpb_load_widget' );

/* Stop Adding Functions Below this Line */
?>
```

It may not be technically correct and it's a bit messy but it works.

Comment: If you figured it out you should post your updated code as an answer.